# JPA Entity Inheritance with abstract classes - ConstrainViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, entity

I am trying to set up Entity Inheritance using JPA annotations and abstract classes.

Our goal is to have the DAO work with the base object through its extension so that we can have mutations of the same application by using a different entity extension, pointcuts and overrides without having to change providers and managers.

example:
The base application stack has a DAO provider that uses an abstract Company entity to persist all objects that extend Company:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Company  extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String register_number;           

    // ...
}

@Component
public class CompanyProvider extends JpaProvider<Company, Long> {
// provides CRUD methods via an EntityManager
}
```

(JPAProvider Setup for reference: )

```
public abstract class JpaProvider<T, ID extends Serializable> implements JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
```

Application A extends the Company to CompanyDefault adding its own columns but without changing the DAO. Application B should do the same:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class CompanyDefault  extends Company {    

    private String name;  

}
```

The persistence.xml exists once for each application(or UnitTest) so this should define the actual entity:

```
<persistence ... >
    <persistence-unit name="persistanceUnit"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <class>path.to.CompanyDefault</class>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now to create a Company I do the following:

```
@Inject
private CompanyProvider companyProvider;    

@Test
public void testAbstractCompany() {
    Company company = new CompanyDefault("123");
    ((CompanyDefault)company).setName("test");

    companyProvider.save(company);
}
```

The unsatisfying result is a ConstraintVioloationException telling me I have a duplicate entry for the primary key:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [...CompanyDefault]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1154)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy37.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:328)
    at ....JpaProvider.save(JpaProvider.java:287)
    at ....JpaProvider$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2caf68f6.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
    at ....CompanyProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d3a45b31.save(<generated>)
    at ....PersonManagerTest.testAbstractCompany(PersonManagerTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [....CompanyDefault]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2454)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2854)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '8' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1038)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3563)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2693)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2102)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2313)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2298)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2437)
    ... 56 more
```

Now why would hibernate try to persist the same entity twice?

What about my Setup and the annotations?

Is what we want to do possible to do: Saving entities by using extensions of an abstract class?

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Edit:**

The same happens if I create and save the extended object directly:

```
@Test
public void testAbstractCompany() {      
    CompanyDefault companyDefault = new CompanyDefault("123");
    companyProvider.save(companyDefault);
}
```

**Edit2 - Solved:**

Never mind my text wall, solved it already.. Just a simple mistake copy-pasing google results:

Have to use `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` obviously. I'll close this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved as per edit 2: Sorry to bother you.