# Use abstract class for instance variable in Spring

Tags: java, spring, struts

My issue is that I have a Spring model

```
@Entity
public class PetOwner {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id", nullable = true)
    private Pet pet;
```

with Pet being an abstract class with 2 subclasses Dog and Cat.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Pet {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Set<PetOwner> owners;
}

@Entity
public class Cat extends Pet 

@Entity
public class Dog extends Pet
```

When I create a new PetOwner in a Struts-form and try to bind its pet to either a Dog or Cat object, I get an error on submitting the form:

```
Error creating bean with name 'de.model.Pet': Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [de.model.Pet]: Is it an abstract class?; 
nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
```

How can I tell Spring to initialize the de.model.Dog or de.model.Cat based on the class pet-object?

FYI: I have a PetDAO and PetService, but I am not sure whether they influence this problem.

I appreciate every help!

Comment: *My issue is that I have a Spring model*. But I don't see how Spring is involved here.

Comment: Could this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119678/jpa-entity-inheritance-with-abstract-classes-constrainviolationexception

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would turn `Pet` to an `Interface` and make `Cat` and `Dog` implement it to avoid this kind of problems. Sorry for off-topic!

Anyhow, if you want some member of your class to be dynamically initialized\populated, try the Lookup Method Injection. Read pp. 3.3.4.1 [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html).

If the class that contains the dynamic member was created in scope=singletone (the default for spring bean container) every time you will access the field that has a lookup method assigned, you will get an appropriate object according to the business logic implemented inside the lookup method.

Also, I found this [example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection) in Spring documentation - I think it is very clear. Take a look at "3.4.6.1 Lookup method injection"

When you configure the `PetOwner` class assign a lookup method to its `Pet` member - it will be called whenever you need a new instance of the Pet bean.

Good luck!

Comment: I used an AbstractClass because I want to create a bidirectional mapping between 'Pet' and #PetOwner', which - I have to admit - I did not point out in the snippet above earlier. As far as my understanding goes, I would have to use a @ManyToAny relation from PetOwner to Pet, which cannot be bidirectional.