# JPA: dynamically mapping an Entity to a table based on an instance variable

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Here is the problem i have:

```
class CurrencyPrice {
    @Transient
    String pair;
    float spotPrice;
    Date timeStamp;
}
```

And I have 3 table the names of which stand for "usd value of euro/gbp/yen respectively": usd_euro, usd_gbp & usd_yen. They all have the same 3 columns: id, spotprice, timestamp.

For some reason i cannot have a single table. The transient instance variable 'pair' will have the following values depending on what it represents: "usd_euro", "usd_gbp" & "usd_yen"

1. And depending on the value in 'pair' I want to insert a row in one of the tables, eg: if I have the value "usd_yen" in 'pair' then the object should be persisted in usd_yen table.
2. And when I want to fetch data, I want JPA to decide which table to SELECT from based on the value in 'pair'

This is simple in JDBC but is there a way to do this in JPA?

Thank you.

Comment: I bumped into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505866/how-to-map-one-class-to-different-tables-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations) which in turn refers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997203/jpa-how-to-use-the-same-class-entity-to-map-different-tables). Looks like I have no choice but to have multiple entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this might actually be feasible in JPA now (those threads you cite are quite old), if you can use inheritance on your entity **and** an additional join table **and** if it's acceptable that the ID for each type is not contiguous.

You could basically define your classes like this then:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="curr_base") // choose a suitable name
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="currency", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING) // your join table needs this column in addition to the id
public abstract class CurrencyPrice {
    @Id
    private int id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="usd_euro")
@DiscriminatorValue("usd_euro")
public class UsdEuroPrice extends CurrencyPrice {
    float spotPrice;
    Date timeStamp;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="usd_gbp")
@DiscriminatorValue("usd_euro")
public class UsdGbpPrice extends CurrencyPrice {
    float spotPrice;
    Date timeStamp;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="usd_yen")
@DiscriminatorValue("usd_euro")
public class UsdYenPrice extends CurrencyPrice {
    float spotPrice;
    Date timeStamp;
}
```

I replicated `spotPrice` and `timeStamp` on each subclass so that you don't have to modify your existing table definitions - of course it would be much cleaner to only have them on the superclass/join table.

This mapping allows it for example to perform a `EntityManager.persist(new UsdGbpPrice(...))` and have JPA insert a row into the right table. For more information, look [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Joined.2C_Multiple_Table_Inheritance).

Comment: Hi Hein Blöd, Thank you for the detailed response. Coming to the last part of your answer, is it possible to have GenericEntityManager.persist(CurrencyPrice) instead of UsdGbpPrice? Trying to avoid entity-type (currency-pair) specific fetch/persist functions. In fact NetBeans generates Entity specific JPA controllers - I am trying to work on the generic one. It would be nice if i can do this: GenericEntityManager.persist(CurrencyPrice) and it internally figures out which table the CurrencyPrice should be persisted in, without me having to write/generate/maintain code for each entity type.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself yet, but after reading some threads (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119678/jpa-entity-inheritance-with-abstract-classes-constrainviolationexception)), I'm sure that it should work. You obviously just have to instantiate one of the concrete subclasses at one point, which you can then assign to a field declared with the abstract supertype. That field can then be passed to your GenericEntityManager.